# Compatibility error with set Operator Except to sent differences between two databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to sent certain record from my central database to the sub one for business purpose.We use datacompare functionality in VS2013. But it take alot of resource. Use set operator:Except to sent only records present in the main db and not the sub database. I used a linkser server:INSERT INTO Person(FullName,[photo],[gender],[receiptNo],[Status],[DateCreated])
 Select top(1000)
 FullName,[photo],[gender],[receiptNo],[Status],[DateCreated]

from
   Mylinkservername.Mydatabasename.dbo.Person 
   EXCEPT
  SELECT 
  FullName,[photo],[gender],[receiptNo],[Status],[DateCreated]
  From Person
But am having this error:`The image data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.`
with tables without images it worksfine. I did alot of research but i can seem to fine solutionthat address my case.
    here is my code:

```
`INSERT INTO Person(FullName,[photo],[gender],[receiptNo],[Status],[DateCreated])
 Select top(1000)
 FullName,[photo],[gender],[receiptNo],[Status],[DateCreated]

 from  
   Mylinkservername.Mydatabasename.dbo.Person 
   EXCEPT
  SELECT 
  FullName,[photo],[gender],[receiptNo],[Status],[DateCreated]
  From Person`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `image` data type is deprecated and should not be used in new development.  Look at converting to `nvarchar(max)` or `varbinary(max)` instead.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

MSDN states that "EXCEPT returns distinct rows from the left input query that aren’t output by the right input query" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx
Because you can cannot compare image, you could instead do a LEFT join to the sub database Person table and check where no records exist in sub.

```
INSERT INTO Person(FullName,[photo],[gender],[receiptNo],[Status],[DateCreated])
 Select top(1000)
 l.FullName,l.[photo],l.[gender],l.[receiptNo],l.[Status],l.[DateCreated]
 from  
   Mylinkservername.Mydatabasename.dbo.Person l --linked server query
   LEFT JOIN Person p --local "sub" database table
   ON l.receiptNo = p.receiptNo --or whatever the primary key column(s) is/are
WHERE p.receiptNo is null --not found in local Person table
```

Comment: your solution is correct but i believe adding extra filter is not necessary, the Except Operator will only record record that is not present in the desitionation.

Comment: The issue with using the `Except` operator in your case is that it is *not* compatible with the `image` data type, because it returns the *distinct* rows from the left input query, and a *distinct* comparison cannot be performed on `image` data type.

Answer (score 0):

I just find out  from MSDN that the  set operation Except does not support images:
[The query specification or expression cannot return xml, text, ntext, image, or nonbinary CLR user-defined type columns because these data types are not comparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)